# Is there a way to show the stats of a specified search query (especially for the ones that appear in autocomplete dropdown)?

Tags: google-search

How do I check the popularity of a particular search query in Google? How to see the stats info on it?

Long ago, in the past, I could even see some number at the right side of an item in autocomplete drop-down menu. As for now, I don't know where to find such info.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/) is Google's website for search query stats and rankings. You can look up stats related to actual search queries, in addition to topics (people, places, TV shows, etc.) from the [Google Knowledge Graph](http://searchengineland.com/library/google/google-knowledge-graph).

I do not believe that it gives stats directly related to Google Search's autocorrect feature, but you could use it in conjunction with autocorrect.

Comment: No, this site seems to be very far from being what I am asking about. I tried to type a query in a search input, but got nothing, even for very popular queries.

Comment: Google is, as far as I am aware, the only group with access to stats regarding specific search queries on its site, so Trends is going to be your only source for detailed stats. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.